# Android Studio / kotlin

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I would like to know if my laptop suitable for **Android Studio**(because i faced some problems with it)
My laptop has Intel core i3 @ CPU M 380 2.53 GHz
and 2 GB ram with windows 32-bit

Comment: Have you downloaded and tried it?

Comment: Please don't vandalize your own posts

Answer (score 0):

Android studio version 2.x requirements for windows

- **OS version** : Windows 7 or later
- **RAM** : 3 GB RAM minimum, 8 GB RAM recommended; plus 1 GB for the Android Emulator
- **Disk space** : 500 MB disk space for Android Studio, at least 1.5 GB for Android SDK, emulator system images, and caches
- **Java version** : Java Development Kit (JDK) 8
- **Screen resolution** : 1280x800 minimum screen resolution

As per the above requirements your laptop has *low ram* (ans:as per this reason your laptop is not suitable for latest version 2.x), so you have to upgrade new ram or as per my personal opinion you have to buy new laptop which is fulfill the above requirements